# accessing master page hyperlink from a different controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I am using ASP.NET 3.0 MVC with membership provider. I have to make modification to the default implementation we get with membership related code. I have to move LogOff Hyperlink  in the master page. Initially this link is in-visible but once authentication is succesfful I need to make it visible. This action will  happen from Controller for authentication and I am not sure how to access the hyperlink defined in a master page from a different controller. Any ideas how this could be achieved keeping the spirits of MVC design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create another action in your AccountController to determine if the log off link needs to be displayed. This action has a partial for the html. Call this new action from the master page and check in that action if the log off link needs to be displayed.

```
 @{ Html.RenderAction("displayLogOff", "Account"); }
```

Comment: I need to do the reverse. Once user is authenticated in (AccountController), I want to display this hyperlink.

Comment: Do you want to move the logoff link from the masterpage to your logon page?

Comment: no; keep it in the master page but want to make it visible from one of the content pages

Comment: Doing it with an action in the masterpage means that it checks itself. you don't need to find the control and alter its properties like you would in WebForms.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need to make a modification, as this seems to be the default behaviour, but typically you would use a partial view to display the log off hyperlink. This partial view can run an action, and in this action you would send a model to the view which could include a flag for if the user is currently authenticated. Alternatively, you can just check Request.IsAuthenticated in the partial view directly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand.  The default implementation already does this.  It works regardless of what controller you're using.  The reason is that the master page uses a partial page that specifies the method and controller.